# How to center FFT on the coner of the four center pixels?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I am calculating the Fourier transform of simple 2D shapes (a circle for example). I am buzzed by a behaviour of the FFT I do not understand: whether my shape is centered on one pixel or on the corner of four pixels the resulting FFT is centered on one pixel. Here is a bit of code to explain:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nPix = 1000
pixelCentered = False

X,Y = np.indices((nPix,nPix),dtype=float)
if pixelCentered:
    X -= (nPix)/2 #this is centering my grid on one pixel
    Y -= (nPix)/2 #this is centering my grid on one pixel
else:
    X -= (nPix -1)/2 #this is centering my grid on the corner of four pixels
    Y -= (nPix -1)/2 #this is centering my grid on the corner of four pixels

x = X/(nPix/2)
y = Y/(nPix/2)
R = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
I = (R<0.5).astype(float)
PSF = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(I))

plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
plt.imshow(I)

plt.figure(2)
plt.clf()
plt.imshow(np.abs(PSF))
```

Since my grid is even, the exact center of the grid is at the corner of the four central pixels. However I create my shape based on the coordinate system `X, Y` and then I can control the position of the center of my shape. If I set `pixelCentered` to `True` the exact center of my grid is on pixel (nPix/2,nPix/2). In this case I expect my maximum pixel to be pixel (nPix/2,nPix/2). Now, if I set `pixelCentered` to False, The exact center of my array is not inside of a pixel but at the corner of the four center pixels. In this case I expect in the FFT that the four central pixel have the maximum value. But this is not what I observe. In fact regardless of the displacement I impose on the circle, the maximum of the FFT of my circle is always centered on the pixel (nPix/2,nPix/2).

What am I missing here? Why is the maximum intensity not moving around with the shape?
Cheers,

Comment: You shift values in the spatial domain, correct? This doesn't cause a frequency shift in the frequency domain. It causes a phase shift. If you plot the phase instead of the absolute value, you should see a difference.

Comment: Yes I do my displacement in the spatial domain, okay I see your point, I tried and indeed. Then does it means that I need to create a phase shift to get my displacement?

Comment: Yes, a displacement in the spatial (or time) domain is a phase shift in the frequency domain. As a point of comparison: If you do an FFT of a sine and cosine wave, you expect both to have the peak in the same frequency bin, right? Their only difference would be the 90° phase shift. It's the same with your stuff.

Comment: yes okay that makes sense... I did not think about it that way, thanks! I guess I'll try to write my own answer then. ^^'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Homer512 comments I can safely answer my own question. Basically the trick is to add a phase in the spatial domain of pi/2. This is only valid if you play with your zero padding without changing your coordinate system.
Here is some example code for you to play with:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
nPix = 1000

X,Y = np.indices((nPix,nPix),dtype=float)
X -= (nPix)/2 #this is centering my grid on one pixel
Y -= (nPix)/2 #this is centering my grid on one pixel

x = X/(nPix/2)
y = Y/(nPix/2)
R = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)

oversampling = 5
I = (R<(1/oversampling)).astype(float)
phase = -(np.pi/2*x)-(np.pi/2*y) #phase you add to center the image
complexPhase = I * np.exp(1j*phase)

plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
plt.imshow(I)
PSF = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(np.fft.fftshift(complexPhase)))

plt.figure(2)
plt.clf()
plt.imshow(np.real(PSF*np.conj(PSF)))
plt.ylim([496,504])
plt.xlim([496,504])
```

Now, if you prefer re scaling your x and y to get your shape sized properly, and still get the FFT centered on the geometrical center of the grid this is how you should do it:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nPix = 1000

X,Y = np.indices((nPix,nPix),dtype=float)
X -= (nPix)/2 #this is centering my grid on one pixel
Y -= (nPix)/2 #this is centering my grid on one pixel

oversampling = 2

x = X/(nPix/2)*oversampling
y = Y/(nPix/2)*oversampling
R = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)

I = (R<1).astype(float)
#Now your additional phase should scale with the oversampling
phase = -(np.pi/oversampling/2*x)-(np.pi/oversampling/2*y)
complexPhase = I * np.exp(1j*phase)

plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
plt.imshow(I)
PSF = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(np.fft.fftshift(complexPhase)))
plt.figure(2)
plt.clf()
plt.imshow(np.real(PSF*np.conj(PSF)))
plt.ylim([496,504])
plt.xlim([496,504])
```

I hope this is clear.

Special note for opticians: this is very annoying because if you do wavefront sensing and use FFT in your reconstructions, it means that you will always get an offset tip/tilt phase due to you trying to center the PSF in the array. Which is not the natural state of the FFT.

Comment: This is weird, I don’t think you fully understand the DFT (FFT). The origin is always at the leftmost sample, with index 0, both in the spatial and in the frequency domain. `fftshift` shifts the origin from the 0 index to index `size//2`, and `ifftshift` shifts it back again from the middle to the left (this behavior extends naturally to any number of dimensions). (1/2)

Comment: Now, the origin in the frequency domain represents the 0 frequency. I don’t understand why anyone would want to move it from there. Your phase shift, equivalent to just shifting the frequency domain by half a pixel, changes the meaning of the frequency bins. These no longer have a physical meaning! (2/2)

Comment: I want to shift the "center frequency", because I want to center this thing on other masks that come later. I do not want to have to fiddle around with coordinate system to get the following mask centered on the central term. Another application of shifting around the zero order of the FFT is to reproduce star images light scattering on a detector. It is not unlikely that the star image does not land exactly on a pixel. This is not necessarily due to a phase error but simply the result of where the star is in the field of view, or the detector centering on the objective optical axis.